# How to debug containerized Queue and Time Trigger Azure Functions and Web Jobs?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-functions, azure-aks

We have deployed an API, an Azure function, and a web job in AKS. Using the Bridge to Kubernetes tool, we can debug the API's services.

Is there any way to debug queue and time trigger Azure functions and web jobs that are deployed on AKS?

Comment: Refer this blog to monitor your AKS- https://dev.to/mfengineering/how-to-monitor-your-azure-kubernetes-cluster-p1b

Answer (score 0):

One way is to integrate the [**`Application Insights`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/kubernetes-codeless) in your **`Azure Function`** to debug and send custom logs to it.

You can refer this [Function sample](https://github.com/ormikopo1988/AzureFunctionsAppInsightsIntegration) where Application insights is integrated with the Function.

You can also use Prometheus and Grafana dashboard to monitor and debug your AKS:-

Reference [**here**](https://dev.to/mfengineering/how-to-monitor-your-azure-kubernetes-cluster-p1b).

Run the below commands to get the dashboard of your AKS:-

```bash
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
kubectl cluster-info
```

**Output:-**

[image]

You can also make use of Log analytics to monitor your AKS:-

From your AKS Send logs to Log Analytics Workspace:-

[image]

You can refer this [**MS document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/logging-monitoring) to monitor your AKS end to end.

***Azure Monitor:-***

[image]

[image]